# whats wrong?(NumberFormatException: null)

Tags: java, numberformatexception

```
    import java.io.*;
    class AccountInfo {

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int age;
    private float accountBalance;
    protected AccountInfo(final String last,final String first,final int ag,final float balance) throws IOException{

        lastName=last;
        firstName=first;
        age=ag;
        accountBalance=balance;
    }
    public void saveState(final OutputStream stream){try{

        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(osw);
        bw.write(lastName);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(firstName);
        bw.write(age);
        bw.write(Float.toString(accountBalance));
        bw.close();}
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println (e);
        }
    } 
    public void restoreState(final InputStream stream)throws IOException{
        try{


            InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(stream);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
            lastName=br.readLine();
            firstName=br.readLine();
            age=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            accountBalance=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
            br.close();}
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println (e);
        }

    }

}
    class accounto{
        public static void main (String[] args) {try{



            AccountInfo obj=new AccountInfo("chaturvedi","aayush",18,18);
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("Account.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("Account,txt");
            obj.saveState(fos);
            obj.restoreState(fis);}
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println (e);
        }
    }
}
```

im getting the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at AccountInfo.restoreState(accounto.java:43)
    at accounto.main(accounto.java:60)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your code:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
//...
age=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

And here is the documentation of [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) (bold mine):

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, **or `null` if the end of the stream has been reached**

In fact, you never really check whether EOF was reached. Can you be that certain about your input (turns out you can't).

Also for [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> **Throws:**
>
> `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

`null` is hardly a "*parsable integer*". The simplest solution is to check your input and handle errors somehow:

```
String ageStr = br.readLine();
if(ageStr != null) {
  age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())
} else {
  //decide what to do when end of file
}
```

Comment: but why is there a null where the integer 18 is supposed to be?

Comment: @AayushChaturvedi: what? You mean a default value? `age = ageStr != null? Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()) : 18`?

Answer (score 3):

From this line:

```
Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

So it looks like you're reading the end of the stream so `br.readLine()` is null. And you can't parse null into an int.

Answer (score 3):

The `br.readLine()` method is returning null, which can't be converted into an Integer - the likely reason for this is that the end of the stream has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I think the value returned from `br.readLine()` is **null**.

**2.** So it **can NOT be converted from String to Integer**.

**3.** Thats the reason you are getting `NumberFormatException`

**4.** To handle this, Wrap that code into `try/catch` block.

```
 try{

        age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


  }catch(NumberFormatException ex){


        System.out.println("Error occured with during conversion");
 }
```